# Transverality Condition $u_t+uu_x=-2u$

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, transversality

> I am given the quasi-linear PDE, 
>   $$u_t+uu_x=-2u,$$ with the boundary condition $u(0,t)=e^{-t}$.

I am trying to compute the transversality condition. I proceed as

$$\text{det}(J)=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial t}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial s }&\frac{\partial t}{\partial s}\\
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=0.$$
I was wondering if the condition is compute correctly ($J$ denotes the Jacobian matrix).

Comment: I cannot understand what you intend to do with this Jacobian where new symbols $s$ and $t$ just come from nowhere. The method of characteristics leads to the solution $$u(x,t)=-x+\sqrt{x^2+e^{-2t}}$$ . If it is that you are looking for, of course we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I try to derive this result before asking for more help. Also, if anyone is able to help with this question, I'd really appreciate it.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140776/similarity-solution-method-of-frac-partial-u-partial-t-alpha-frac-partia

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140885/method-of-characteristics-for-u-t-uu-x-2u

Comment: @JJacquelin if only someone had the same similarity solution question :(